# More than 11 players

Tags: football

Is there any instance of more than 11 players from one team, on field during a professional football match? If yes, then what action was taken against the team?

Comment: [This question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/15575/15589) describes a friendly match between Dinamo Moscow and Arsenal in which Dinamo allegedly ended up with 12 men at one point due to foggy conditions. I'm not posting it as an answer, since it was only a friendly and not a competitive fixture, but it's still worth mentioning.

Answer (score 8):

A well documented occasion happened during the Dutch national championship in 2015, Utrecht versus Ajax. Edouard Duplan, Utrecht's forward, had an injury and left the field for medical attention. Meanwhile, the coach replaced him with Tommy Oar.

However, Duplan recovered and stepped into the field again without realising that Oar had already replaced him. It took two minutes until the referee realised the issue, apparently because people were laughing and booing.

[image]

In the image above you can see 11 players (12 with the goalkeeper, which is not visible).

Here is a link (disclaimer, I don't speak Dutch): https://www.voetbalprimeur.nl/nieuws/430022/duplan-over-lachwekkend-moment-dus-ik-dacht-dat-kan-maar-n-ding-zijn-.html?itm_source=www.voetbalprimeur.nl&itm_medium=Navigatie%20Pijltjes

---

PS: In the [comment below](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/24238/more-than-11-players/24240#comment33191_24240) OP asks if any action was taken. Despite not finding anything online I don't think that that was the case, because everybody saw that Duplan made a mistake in good faith. That, for instance, is very different from what happened in the Santos vs Corinthians match for the Brazilian championship in 2006, in which Santos' coach **deliberately** put 12 players in the field for the kick-off, just to cause confusion (*"confusion and delay"*, I should say, because it took 15 minutes for the match to start).

Comment: Was any action taken against them?

Comment: @adithskv I didn't find anything regarding this, but I don't think so: everybody saw that the mistake was done in good faith.

Comment: https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/spielbericht/index/spielbericht/2459843 according to this report no action was taken. A mistake like that should lead to a yellow card for Duplan, but he was lucky in this case.

Comment: @dly that's funny: can a player **already replaced** receive an yellow card? I reckon he can, but still it's an interesting question.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Even a red card would be possible.

Comment: @dly that's interesting... but what's the practical effect of a red card for a player that has already left the field? A suspension for the next game?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado correct. A suspension for the next game(s) for that player and the team can keep all players on the pitch in such a case.